# GridLayout hgap vgap "not working" on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

```
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout (6,7,0,0);
    grid.setLayout (layout);

    slot = new ImageIcon ("");

    for (int x = 0; x < 42; ++x)
    {
        slotbtn = new JButton(slot);
        slotbtn.setContentAreaFilled (false);
        //slotbtn.setBorderPainted (false);
        slotbtn.setBorder (BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (0,0,0,0));
        slotbtn.setFocusPainted (false);
        grid.add(slotbtn);
    }
```

This is the output I get:
[image]

I am creating a 6x7 grid. The output I need is for there to be no space in between the rows and columns, everything should be compressed together. I tried pack and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

-- I tried FlowLayout but I had to resize the frame and I have other buttons on the frame so I don't think I'd prefer resizing it to make the buttons fit in their proper places.
-- I placed this JPanel inside another jpanel(which uses borderlayout and contains two other panels) and I placed it at the center, the two other panels North and South.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, I got it working now. Really thanks for the effort, I'll just vote up everybody's answer

Answer (score 2):

this issue because you divide the `grid` (the whole size of grid) to `7*6` so if you re-size the window you will see this gaps changed so if you wan't to remove this gab

1. calculate the size of the window (ex: width = 7* width of your image , hight = 6*hight of your mage)
2. or re-size your image

Comment: If I will resize my image, how will I know how big it should be?

Comment: what you mean by "how big" ? you will make the grid size fixed and then get the width and height for it , then divide the width / 7 and the height /6 (or any value you want) , the resize your image to new one , but if the image so small it will make a distortion and if it so big it will take a time

Comment: I was talking about resizing my image to make it fit the button bc you suggested that i resize my image. I just decided to resize the frame  and I guess I'm okay with it now I'll just find another way with the other buttons thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

`JButton` employs a `margin` property to provide additional padding to the content area of the button, you could try using...

```
slotbtn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

I would also try using something like `slotbtn.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));` to determine if the spacing is from the button, icon or layout

`GridLayout` will also provide each cell with equal amount of space, based on the available space to the container, this means that the cell may increase beyond the size of the icon.

While a little more work, `GridBagLayout` would (if configured properly) honour the preferred size of each component.

Have a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I get no margins using your code, with *any* image I use. Check your image. And maybe post a runnable example replicating the problem. Maybe there's something going on you're not showing us. I'd start by checking the image for margins. Check it against this. If it still has margins, than its your image. Also, **Don't** set the size to anything! You may be stretching the panel unnecessarily, which *will* cause the gaps. Also if there an of your other panels are larger than the grip panel, it will also cause it to stretch. But take **all** your `set(Xxx)size`s out and see what happens. Just `pack()`

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestButtonGrid {

    public TestButtonGrid() {

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow3.png"));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 7));

        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            JButton slotbtn = new JButton(icon);
            slotbtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            //slotbtn.setBorderPainted (false);
            slotbtn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
            slotbtn.setFocusPainted(false);
            panel.add(slotbtn);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestButtonGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer and the effort i fixed it now thanks for the help!